# Connecting SpringMVC app to MBaaS for Android Application

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, mbaas

I'm trying to create native Android app with MBaaS e.g. on parse.com where clients could enter some data. The thing is that I would also like to create some admin side web app (e.g. in Java SpringMVC) which could read that user related info from MBaaS service. Is it possible to connect SpringMVC app to MBaaS service? If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com has REST API to access your data, so you can write separate web application with admin interface and fetch data from Parse.com via REST API.

But remember that Parse.com won't host your Java application. You'll need to host it on your own.

Comment: so it is possible to have baas on parse.com and host Java application on e.g. Huroku (or any other paas) and Java app could communicate with baas via REST API? or I misunderstood something? thx

Comment: Your mobile application can fetch data from MBaaS (like Parse.com) using REST API or their custom SDK for specific platform - for example Parse.com have their own Android SDK which allows you to save and load data from cloud. On the other hand your admin web application can also connect to Parse.com MBaaS using REST API - or maybe parse has also SDK for web appilcation - you need to check it on your own. Everything depends on MBaaS provider. Parse seems to be very good choice for you.